# Is there any better and more idiomatic way of taking "while not enough" from a seq?

Tags: clojure

I need to take some amount of elements from a sequence based on some quantity rule. Here is a solution I came up with:

```
(defn take-while-not-enough
[p len xs]
(loop [ac 0
       r []
       s xs]
       (if (empty? s)
            r
            (let [new-ac (p ac (first s))]
                (if (>= new-ac len)
                    r
                    (recur new-ac (conj r (first s)) (rest s)))))))

(take-while-not-enough + 10 [2 5 7 8 2 1]) ; [2 5]

(take-while-not-enough #(+ %1 (%2 1)) 7 [[2 5] [7 8] [2 1]]) ; [[2 5]]
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Somebody posted that solution, but then removed it. It does the same is the answer that I accepted, but is more readable. Thank you, anonymous well-wisher!

```
(defn take-while-not-enough [reducer-fn limit data] 
   (->> (reductions reducer-fn 0 data)      ; 1. the sequence of accumulated values
        (map vector data)                   ; 2. paired with the original sequence
        (take-while #(< (second %) limit))  ; 3. until a certain accumulated value
        (map first)))                       ; 4. then extract the original values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to view this problem as a variation on reduce and thus to break the problem into two steps:

- count the number of items in the result
- take that many from the input

I also took some liberties with the argument names:

```
user> (defn take-while-not-enough [reducer-fn limit data] 
       (take (dec (count (take-while #(< % limit) (reductions reducer-fn 0 data)))) 
             data)) 
#'user/take-while-not-enough 

user> (take-while-not-enough #(+ %1 (%2 1)) 7 [[2 5] [7 8] [2 1]])    
([2 5])     

user> (take-while-not-enough + 10 [2 5 7 8 2 1]) 
(2 5)
```

This returns a sequence and your examples return a vector, if this is important then you can add a call to `vec`

Answer (score 1):

Something that would traverse the input sequence only once:

```
(defn take-while-not-enough [r v data]
  (->> (rest (reductions (fn [s i] [(r (s 0) i) i]) [0 []] data))
       (take-while (comp #(< % v) first))
       (map second)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use flatland/useful, this is a kinda-okay way to use [`glue`](https://github.com/flatland/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/seq.clj#L193):

```
(defn take-while-not-enough [p len xs]                                                              
  (first (glue conj []                                                                              
               (constantly true)                                                                    
               #(>= (reduce p 0 %) len)                                                             
               xs)))
```

But it's rebuilding the accumulator for the entire "processed so far" chunk every time it decides whether to grow the chunk more, so it's O(n^2), which will be unacceptable for larger inputs.

The most obvious improvement to your implementation is to make it lazy instead of tail-recursive:

```
(defn take-while-not-enough [p len xs]                                                                                    
  ((fn step [acc coll]                                                                          
     (lazy-seq                                                                                  
       (when-let [xs (seq coll)]                                                                  
         (let [x (first xs)                                                                     
               acc (p acc x)]                                                                   
           (when-not (>= acc len)                                                               
             (cons x (step acc xs)))))))                                                        
   0 xs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `lazy-seq` is straight-forward and self-explaining.

```
(defn take-while-not-enough
  ([f limit coll] (take-while-not-enough f limit (f) coll))
  ([f limit acc coll]
   (lazy-seq
     (when-let [s (seq coll)]
       (let [fst  (first s)
             nacc (f acc fst)]
         (when (< nxt-sd limit)
           (cons fst (take-while-not-enough f limit nacc (rest s)))))))))
```

Note: `f` is expected to follow the rules of reduce.